# Why does cleaning my Android project generate C++ build system [clean] failed

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake

My current Android application contains some cpp code

It was gradle synching, cleaning, building, and running fine with no errors until i installed the latest version of cmake with homebrew

the version of cmake installed on my mac is 3.24.1

and my Android project has

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.1)
```

and gradle of

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.24.1'
    }
}
```

i can synch gradle, build, refresh linked c++ projects without any issues

however when i clean project i get the following errors

```
> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanDevelopmentDebug FAILED
Clean native-lib-armeabi-v7a
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanDevelopmentRelease FAILED
Clean native-lib-x86
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanProductionDebug FAILED
Clean native-lib-armeabi-v7a
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanProductionRelease FAILED
Clean native-lib-x86
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanStagingDebug FAILED
Clean native-lib-armeabi-v7a
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

> Task :shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanStagingRelease FAILED
Clean native-lib-x86
C/C++: /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
C/C++: ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
```

and this

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 6 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:covert:externalNativeBuildCleanDevelopmentDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/frank/github/mobile-android-showcase/shared/covert/.cxx/Debug/5u70473e/armeabi-v7a'
  [0/1] Re-running CMake...
  FAILED: build.ninja 
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S/Users/frank/github/mobile-android-showcase/shared/covert/src/main/cpp -B/Users/frank/github/mobile-android-showcase/shared/covert/.cxx/Debug/5u70473e/armeabi-v7a
  
  C++ build system [clean] failed while executing:
      /Users/frank/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
        -C \
        /Users/frank/github/mobile-android-showcase/shared/covert/.cxx/Debug/5u70473e/armeabi-v7a \
        clean
    from /Users/frank/github/mobile-android-showcase/shared/covert
  /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.23.2/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
  ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

Android studio only allows me to install highest cmake version of 3.22.1

my gradle file resembles this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.0-beta02'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0-rc01' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0-rc01' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

how can i resolve these project clean errors?

the android studio version i am employing is

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 RC 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.8913347, built on August 6, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8192M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its OK

I found a really simple (if surprising) fix

i searched replaced the entire file system in android studio

replacing `3.23.2` with `3.24.1`

Comment: Can you share what worked for you?